# Implementing RC4 in Python

Tags: python, encryption

I need to implement RC4 in a script in Python and I found these two libraries:

arc4 - https://pypi.org/project/arc4/

Pycryptodome -> https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/arc4.html

Consulting the documentation, I saw the key length has to be at least: 40 bytes (5 characters), but when I use arc4

```
from arc4 import ARC4
ARC4.new("tree")
```

It doesn't display any error

but with:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4
ARC4.new(b"tree")
```

Console displays: ValueError: Incorrect ARC4 key length (4 bytes)

Why this different behavior in two libraries that implement the same cipher?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3138). Furthermore, the minimum key length is typically given as 40 bits, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4), (and not 40 bytes, maybe just a typo on your part).

Answer (score 0):

The second crypto library requires that RC4 keys be between 5 bytes and 256 bytes.  This is in its documentation. I don't know if this is part of the official RC4 specification or not.

What are you using RC4?  It is an extremely weak cipher and has probably been cracked by various three letter agencies.